# Strange way to get system time

Tags: c

I found this macro in my project: `#define OsixGetSysTime(a)           (*a = *a)`

which is called from

```
VOID
UtlGetTime (tUtlTm * tm)  /* tm is a struct that was memset to 0 */
{
    UINT4               u4Ticks;

    OsixGetSysTime (&u4Ticks);
    u4Ticks -= gu4TicksCorr; // gu4TicksCorr is global value
    UtlGetTimeForTicks (u4Ticks, tm);
}
```

And this is the start of `UtlGetTimeForTicks` :

```
VOID
UtlGetTimeForTicks (UINT4 u4Ticks, tUtlTm * tm)
{
    UINT4               u4ElapsedSecs;
    UINT4               u4DaysInYear;
    UINT4               u4Days;
    UINT4               u4Leap;
    UINT4               u4Month;
    UINT4               u4Secs;
    tUtlTm              TmBuf;

    u4ElapsedSecs = u4Ticks / gu4Stups;
```

As you can see, that strange variable is used in other calculations. I'm not sure I can reveal too much of this code :(

This is used in a lot of functions that help manipulate system time. Is this doing something other than unneeded assignment?

Comment: Could you post one of the functions that uses this macro? It's very strange in deed. On what kind of hardware is this code running?

Comment: This looks like a stub designed to be used in lieu of absent functionality and silence compiler warnings.

Comment: note that the macro sucks. what if I pass `pointer+i` ? should be `#define OsixGetSysTime(a)           (*(a) = *(a))` to the least.

Comment: that's nonsense. BTW found this `UINT4
OsixGetSysTime (tOsixSysTime * pSysTime)
{
clock_t CurTicks;
UINT4 u4TicksPerStup;
CurTicks = times (NULL);
*pSysTime = (CurTicks - gStartTicks) * gu4Stups / sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);
return (OSIX_SUCCESS);
}` rings a bell?

Comment: @n.m. this is what I thought, but 1) they have a different macro for that 2) this variable is used and since it's local and the macro does nothing it should be garbage

Comment: Your `UtlGetTime` will expose UB because when you call `UtlGetTimeForTicks(u4Ticks, tm)`, `u4Ticks` will have an indeterminate value.

Comment: So either it is garbage, or there is another definition for `OsixGetSysTime`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz This whole project is the definition of UB :-( I'm trying to fix it piece by piece

Comment: UB feeds C questions, why don't you post your whole code here :)

Comment: now that you understood that the guys who coded that in the first place are clowns, you can delete/recode the whole thing: you can't do worse than that.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! (after extensive search)

The project had a function very much similar to what Jean-François Fabre commented, but the evil eclipse showed me that strange macro instead:

```
UINT4 OsixGetSysTime (tOsixSysTime * pSysTime)
{ 
   clock_t CurTicks;
   UINT4 u4TicksPerStup;
   CurTicks = times (NULL); 
   *pSysTime = (CurTicks - gStartTicks) * gu4Stups / sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK); 
   return (OSIX_SUCCESS); 
}
```

I'm sure that the code compiles with the function, not the macro (because is works with a consistent system time), which makes me wonder why eclipse directed to the macro, but anyways, mystery solved. Thanks everyone